# Symfony does not use CustomAuthenticator method

Tags: php, symfony, symfony5

I created a method in the UserRepository: loadUserByIdentifier and loadUserByUsername. However, these are not addressed. Why?

Actually, a dump output should appear.

Do I have to explicitly specify these methods somewhere in order to be used as a login method?

When I click on Login, the login form simply reloads.

My UserRepository:

```
<?php

namespace App\Repository;

use App\Entity\User;
use Doctrine\Bundle\DoctrineBundle\Repository\ServiceEntityRepository;
use Doctrine\Persistence\ManagerRegistry;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\UnsupportedUserException;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\PasswordAuthenticatedUserInterface;
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Security\User\UserLoaderInterface;
use function get_class;

/**
 * @extends ServiceEntityRepository<User>
 *
 * @method User|null find($id, $lockMode = null, $lockVersion = null)
 * @method User|null findOneBy(array $criteria, array $orderBy = null)
 * @method User[]    findAll()
 * @method User[]    findBy(array $criteria, array $orderBy = null, $limit = null, $offset = null)
 */
class UserRepository extends ServiceEntityRepository implements UserLoaderInterface
{
    public function __construct(ManagerRegistry $registry)
    {
        parent::__construct($registry, User::class);
    }

    public function add(User $entity, bool $flush = false): void
    {
        $this->getEntityManager()->persist($entity);

        if ($flush) {
            $this->getEntityManager()->flush();
        }
    }

    public function remove(User $entity, bool $flush = false): void
    {
        $this->getEntityManager()->remove($entity);

        if ($flush) {
            $this->getEntityManager()->flush();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Used to upgrade (rehash) the user's password automatically over time.
     */
    public function upgradePassword(PasswordAuthenticatedUserInterface $user, string $newHashedPassword): void
    {
        if (!$user instanceof User) {
            throw new UnsupportedUserException(sprintf('Instances of "%s" are not supported.', get_class($user)));
        }

        $user->setPassword($newHashedPassword);

        $this->add($user, true);
    }

    public function findAllUsers($ownUser, $q = null)
    {
        $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('user');
        $query = $qb
            ->select('u')
            ->from('App\Entity\User', 'u')
            ->where('u.firstname LIKE :user')
            ->orWhere('u.lastname LIKE :user')
            ->andWhere($qb->expr()->neq('u.id', $ownUser))
            ->setParameter('user',  $q)
            ->setParameter('user', '%'. $q . '%')
            ->orderBy('u.firstname', 'ASC')
            ->distinct()
            ->getQuery();
        return $query->getArrayResult();
    }

    public function loadUserByUsername(string $usernameOrEmail)
    {
        dump($usernameOrEmail);
        exit();
        return $this->loadUserByIdentifier($usernameOrEmail);
    }

    public function loadUserByIdentifier(string $usernameOrEmail): ?User
    {

        if (!filter_var($usernameOrEmail, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
            $name = explode(" ", $usernameOrEmail);
            dump($name);
            exit();
        }

        return $this->createQueryBuilder('u')
            ->where('u.email = :emailOrUsername')
            ->orWhere('u.username = :emailOrUsername')
            ->setParameter('emailOrUsername', $usernameOrEmail)
            ->getQuery()
            ->getOneOrNullResult();
    }

//    /**
//     * @return User[] Returns an array of User objects
//     */
//    public function findByExampleField($value): array
//    {
//        return $this->createQueryBuilder('u')
//            ->andWhere('u.exampleField = :val')
//            ->setParameter('val', $value)
//            ->orderBy('u.id', 'ASC')
//            ->setMaxResults(10)
//            ->getQuery()
//            ->getResult()
//        ;
//    }

//    public function findOneBySomeField($value): ?User
//    {
//        return $this->createQueryBuilder('u')
//            ->andWhere('u.exampleField = :val')
//            ->setParameter('val', $value)
//            ->getQuery()
//            ->getOneOrNullResult()
//        ;
//    }
}
```

My security.yaml:

```
security:
    enable_authenticator_manager: true
    # https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#registering-the-user-hashing-passwords
    password_hashers:
        Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\PasswordAuthenticatedUserInterface: 'auto'
        App\Entity\User:
            algorithm: auto

    # https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#loading-the-user-the-user-provider
    providers:
        # used to reload user from session & other features (e.g. switch_user)
        app_user_provider:
            entity:
                class: App\Entity\User
        # used to reload user from session & other features (e.g. switch_user)
    firewalls:
        dev:
            pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
            security: false
        main:
            lazy: true
            provider: app_user_provider
            logout:
                path: app_logout
```

Comment: Hi. I also use a custom query to load the user. If that's what you want to do, I think you should look there https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/user_providers.html#using-a-custom-query-to-load-the-user. I think you are using the loadUserByIdentifier method incorrectly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The better way is to do that (according to the Symfony doc [here](https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/user_providers.html#using-a-custom-query-to-load-the-user)) :

You have to remove the property key from the user provider in security.yaml and write it like that :

```
# config/packages/security.yaml
security:
    providers:
        users:
            entity:
                class: App\Entity\User
    # ...
```

And adapt this function to coresspond with the doc :

```
public function loadUserByIdentifier(string $usernameOrEmail): ?User
    {
        $entityManager = $this->getEntityManager();

        return $entityManager->createQuery(
                'SELECT u
                FROM App\Entity\User u
                WHERE u.username = :query
                OR u.email = :query'
            )
            ->setParameter('query', $usernameOrEmail)
            ->getOneOrNullResult();
    }
```

**Also you have to remove `enable_authenticator_manager: true`.**

---

**EDIT (to answer your question)**

Regarding your question, here is the minimum `main' firewall configuration:

```
main:
   anonymous: ~
   form_login:
      login_path: app_login
      check_path: app_login
   logout:
      path: app_logout
```

Comment: Thank you, but now it says: No authentication listener registered for firewall "main".

My security.yaml firwalls:

    `firewalls:
        dev:
            pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
            security: false
        main:
            lazy: true
            provider: app_user_provider
            logout:
                path: app_logout`

Comment: If I remove provider: app_user_provider in main: firewalls, I get the error: No authentication listener registered for firewall "main".

Comment: Please check my EDIT @Luis

Comment: And do you have write you provider like me ?

Comment: I have now adjusted it so, but the login page just reloads. https://pastebin.com/5UztJ7CA

check_path: I removed it because I don’t know what it is needed for.

Comment: What must be behind default_target_path?

Comment: Oops it was a mistake on my part. Please try again with my latest changes.